# Remove confirmation when using DoCmd.RunSQL for INSERT and DELETE

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I am using the DoCmd.RunSQL method to INSERT and DELETE records based on actions that a user makes in a form. It works fine but it asks for a confirmation before deleting or appending a record. How can I remove the confirmation.

By the way, the BeforeDelConfirm event doesn't seem to run with DoCmd.RunSQL.

Comment: `Application.DisplayAlerts = False`?

Comment: Thank you. I think Application.DisplayAlerts is only for Excel. I found an equivalent though. DoCmd.SetWarnings. Don't know why they weren't more consistent across excel and access.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Rather than using `DoCmd.RunSql` to run your SQL and worrying about alerts you can use this.

```
Dim sql as string
Dim dbs as DAO.Database
set dbs = CurrentDb()

sql = "INSERT INTO table(field1) VALUES(1)"
dbs.Execute sql, dbFailOnError

dbs.close
set dbs = nothing
```

Comment: Thank you. I ended up using DoCmd.SetWarnings. I learned something new anyway because I didn't know you could run SQL commands like that as well.

Comment: Turning `SetWarnings` off suppresses information, so can make trouble-shooting difficult.  (Search SO for ms-access plus SetWarnings)  `Database.Execute` is better, especially with the `dbFailOnError` option Zaider wisely included.  +1